# Can tantra be linked to Bhakti?

Tags: tantra, bhakti, siddhi

Among the different types of Bhakti,a/the prominent type is where one is simply in love with his/her aaradhya,and worships simply because he/she loves the deity ,displaying nishkama Bhakti.

Tantric practices,from sadhnas of the Dasha Mahavidyas ,and then “siddhi” of other/lower beings like Pishach,Dakini,Vetal, etc.,all are aimed at acquiring certain powers from the deities.

My question is :Do tantric practices have any scope of the madhurya bhaav of bhakti,as mentioned above?

Question 2:Via tantric practices,is the deity worshipped, “forced”/compelled,to give the sadhak’s desired objective?

(If Q2 ‘s answer is yes,then how does maadhurya bhav exist in tantra(if at all it does),considering that no bhakt immersed in maadhurya bhav will want to “force” his aaradhya to bestow a certain boon/power...??)

Comment: How said tantra is aimed only for siddhis? Tantra is beyonds siddhis. Just people r very misinformed. Btw, what is Madhurya Bhaav firstly one can never attain it as it's path is just like walking on a rope [Altough a few sadhakas (just 2*3)  have accomplished it.] Thus, everyone tends to follow Vatsalya Bhaav. And as ur second question is concerned, I already mentioned tantra is behind asking boons and siddhis. These daily soaps have spread nnsense in masses that one can force a devi by tantra. Lol, she us Adishakti not even Rudra can force her! She does only by  her will. And its not forcing

Comment: Tantra works on the principal that proper mantra with proper samagri will give desired result. Just like, in chem Lab, u add two reactants and get a final product. Same way, the deity is a catalyst who makes the reaction happen without herself getting involved directly (Because it was u who added reactants ). Even even if explosion happens as end product, it's on your result and ur liable to bear it alone as, deity was just a catalyst. Hope u get the Analogy. Thus, tantra offers more than such wordly pursuits which is  by paving the path to Moksha of the individual.